# Is it possible to have a better position on Google then my partners sites

Tags: seo, google

I have a site like a marketplace. I sell what my partners sell on their sites. When someone search for some partner company name on Google, my partners site appear at first position and my site at second position.

Each partner has an exclusive page on my website, like: `www.mydomain.com/partner`

So, will Google always show the company website first, or there are some chance to my website to appear first? It depends only of SEO relevance or this is a Google feature?

Comment: There's no specific feature that I know of. This is just Google SEO as usual afaik.

Comment: @dm777 `So, will Google always show the company website first, or there are some chance to my website to appear first?` Since the company likely had its content indexed prior to partner sites, and also likely has brand relevance associated with the products, partner sites should rank lower in search results. The only thing you can do to rank over other partners is to improve your content as compared to theirs. See:  [What are the best ways to increase a site's position in Google?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-are-the-best-ways-to-increase-a-sites-position-in-google)